# Linking gfortran libraries to c++ program in CodeBlocks under Ubuntu

Tags: linker, g++, codeblocks, gfortran

I have an Ubuntu under Vmware, and use Code::Blocks, as I am not a very powerful command line user
and prefer IDE to Vim+console.

I am trying to compile a program which uses a c++ wrapper to fortran library.
However compiling gives me the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `_gfortran_compare_string'
```

There are a lot of errors of this type and a bunch of other similar to this one.

I have gfortran 4.6.3. I found searching that it is probably a linking problem, and people say to
use -lgfortran option for linker. When I add this to linker options in the Code::Blocks it does not change anything, errors continue. So, here are some question:

1. Is this a correct option for linker?
2. May be I have to give linker a direct path to the fortran library?
3. How do I find where are the fortran libraries installed? (I don't know a lot about linux ((( )
4. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Whas this Fortran library compiled with the same version of `gfortran` that you have installed? Otherwise it might require symbols from another version of `libgfortran.so`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added gfortran as a library to linked to your project or lgfortran? The l is just an option for the g++ for linking the library gfortran to your code. I am not familar with Code::Blocks but you should look for a place where you can enter libraries you want to use and add the gfortran directly. 
My guess is that the Code::Blocks side can help you to find this place.

Kim Kulling

Comment: Yes, I know where I can enter libraries in Code::Blocks. However I don't know where are gfortran libraries located in linux, or which files from the libraries I actually should add. Maybe just pass the whole directory to linker?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something like /bin/lib /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. Just take a look into your filesystem. Unfortunately I do not have a Linuix at work. Maybe someone else?

Kim Kulling

Comment: Yeah, I tried to search with something like `find /usr -name gfortran` but find only binary gfortran and docs, but no libraries. Maybe I don't understand something. Maybe somebody will tell me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You should try with `find /usr -name \*gfortran\*`. The library is most likely `/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.1` or `/usr/lib/gfortran.so.3` or it might be in `/usr/lib64` if running on 64-bit Linux. It could also be someplace else if `gfortran` comes not from distro package.